# A problem on conditional probability

Tags: probability

[image]

In the above problem, $P(A)$ is the probability that one of the tubes drawn is good ,so $\frac{(6C_1+6C_2)}{10C_2} =\frac{7}{15}$ . So I'm getting a  final answer of $\frac{5}{7}$.
Which one is correct?
Please explain

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the original question, as stated, is $5/9$.  The solution has stated the event $A$ incorrectly; it should be "the *first* tube is good", not "one tube is good".

There are $\binom{10}{2} = 45$ ways to select two tubes, of which $\binom{6}{2} = 15$ select two good tubes, $4 \times 6 = 24$ select one good and one bad, and $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ select two bad tubes.

The probability of $A$—that the *first* tube tests good—is therefore $15/45+(24/45)(1/2) = 1/3+4/15 = 3/5$.  That's because when you select one good tube and one bad, you have only a $1/2$ chance of testing the good tube first.

Therefore

$$
P(B \mid A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{1/3}{3/5} = \frac{5}{9}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The phrases "one of the tubes is tested and is found to be good" is different from "at least one of the tubes is good."  The difference is that in the former, we only know about the first tube.  You seem to be attempting to calculate the odds, based on at least one being good.

As a shorthand, if you did the test before drawing the second tube, you would have: "One tube is drawn and tested and shown to be good.  Another tube is drawn.  What is the probability that it is good?"  Clearly, in this case, there are 9 tubes left, of which 5 are good, so the probability is $5/9$.

Whether you draw the second tube before or after the test has no effect on which tubes are drawn, so the correct answer must be the same.

The explanation is using the formula $P(B|A) = {P(A \cap B) \over P(A)}$ to calculate the conditional probability.